# Automatic screenshots with cursor

Tags: linux, screenshot

I want to automatically capture my desktop every 5 seconds and create a one day time-lapsed video of my work.

- Ideally, I want to be able to store images in Google Drive/Dropbox so I don't take up a bunch of space on my hard drive.
- I am on Linux and would prefer to use a terminal command for doing this.

I've been trying out the [Scrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot) command line tool for this, but it doesn't capture my desktop cursor.

Does anyone know of other options that capture the cursor and might be a better tool for this?

Comment: I posted a solution for scoot but just noticed you had tried it. I deleted my answer. sorry.

Comment: Does scrot have an option to include cursor  maybe?  scrot -C possibly?

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed from the bug fix listing that [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) has corrected the problem with the cursor capture in the recent version. I have been unable to determine a timer reference as noted in your request. Additionally, I'm unable to address the file store location, as my Linux box is down for the count at the moment.

It appears to be a project continuing from 2011 and still active today. I expect to install and test it in the coming weeks. The price of free is, as always, difficult to beat, if it serves your purpose.

Update: having completed a test install of Shutter, I can confirm that the cursor can be included in the capture. I can also confirm off-site capability as there is a section in the preferences covering FTP connections as well as plug-ins to allow Dropbox and Imgur among others.

In my search, I see references to timed capture, yet have not been able to pin that portion down.